# How to trim video with AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation, trim

For additional export options I create AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter objects to transcode and output the video asset’s data.

I want to trim this video use AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter.

I find others use AVAssetExportSession to trim a video, then use AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter to compress.

Can't I merge these two steps together?

Comment: Please share code when you ask question if you want we help you about your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AVAssetReader` has a property named `timeRange` - you can specify time range which you need to proceed, so this will allow you to trim your output file

Comment: Could you show example if you have ? or pls answer to this question, really don't understand how to make it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70184498/trim-video-always-fail-when-use-avassetexportpresetpassthrough